# On Coordinate Geometry and the Triangular Inequality.

Tags: inequality, triangles, coordinate-systems

We have three Points P(2,3),Q(4,-2) and R(x,0).We need to find the value of  x  such that:
[image: The Triangle]

Case1 : PR+RQ is maximum.
x=16/5

Case 2 : PR-RQ is minimum.
x=8

I absolutely have no idea how to solve this.We need to solve x for both the cases.

Comment: What are the values of $PR$ and $RQ$ in terms of $x$?

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe here x is a variable

Comment: For example, $PR=\sqrt{ {(3-0)}^2+{(2-x)}^2}$

Comment: Pssst... first one , a case of ellipse. Second one, a case of hyperbola ;)

Comment: Have you not given some information here? PR +RQ is maximum? Obviously it's at $x$ ($\alpha$) $\to \infty$.

Comment: I have the solutions though. I have understood case 1: https://imgur.com/a/ymUvM  but not case 2 https://imgur.com/a/lLK9k

Comment: I didnt understand why in case 2 they had to take image of point Q and draw a new triangle.

Comment: @TheDeadLegend Details added